# Why I get a "D" after the first number of my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, output

I recently made this simple software in Java that is supposed to scan some integers, search for duplicates, remove them from the ArrayList and show the new ArrayList with no duplicate values.

Everything works fine but the first number i put in the input flow (no matter which number is) is always gave back with a letter "D" after it.

I know it stands for Double, maybe I know bad lol, but anyway why is it there?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(in.hasNext()){
            A.add(in.nextInt());      
        }

        for (int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
            for (int j=0;j<A.size();j++){
            if (i==j)
                continue;
            else
                if (A.get(i)==A.get(j)){
                    A.remove(j);
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int n=0;n<A.size();n++){
            System.out.println(A.get(n));
        }

    }
}
```

Input:

```
0 -1 5 -1 -1 2 0 2
```

Output:

```
0D
-1
5
2
```

Input:

```
0 0 0 0
```

Output:

```
0D
```

Input:

```
1 1 1 1
```

Output:

```
1D
```

[Consolle Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0VrG.png)

Comment: Tip: Hashsets prevent duplicates as soon as you add. matching elements  to them

Comment: Is it always the first number, or is it just zero? Also, `ArrayList<Integer>` can never contain doubles, so your assumptions seem off

Comment: cannot reproduce

Comment: Something happend to your indentation. Two closing curly brackets on the same vertical position, following each other, is an indentation smell.

Comment: @cricket_007 no, with every number i put as the first value. I know that my arraylist can't contain double, for that I said that probably I knew bad about that "D" char.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include more input and output examples? Also, please fix the non matching brackets

Answer (score -2):

Your code is working fine & giving expected result.D is not coming. You should check your input data and IDE.

As you didn't restricted your number of integer numbers, It's taking inputs and inputs  continue.......

I have modified like this for 10 integer numbers. You can try it.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
       while(in.hasNext() && A.size() != 10){
               A.add(in.nextInt());      

   }
```

Comment: The input is limited with `hasNext`. The size is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know the input does not stop, it's made on purposed. The exercise asked to let it continue until the user ends the flow (with CTRL + D)